# How to make Sphinx generate "last modified" from access time of source files for individual pages?

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm working on a documentation project with sphinx and the ReadTheDocs theme. The source files are in a git repo on gitlab, and I use automatic testing to check that the documentation builds properly with every merge into the master branch. I am able to store the successfully built html files on gitlab and sync them to my private server. However, because the documentation is always built from scratch during automatic tests, the "Last Modified" flag on the pages is always at the time of the last build of the pages. I'd like to avoid that and keep the "Last Modified" flag true, i.e. I'd like it to display the actual last modification time of the source .rst file. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Kevin Horn's answer, I added the following to my build script that is executed on the gitlab server automatically for continuous integration:

```
#!/bin/bash

#=============================================================================
# Automatically add last modified date according to last commit date
#=============================================================================

# first store all the files that are modified;
# don't want them to be added automatically to the commit
# without you noticing!

modfiles=`git ls-files -m`



# Add or update dates to the file

for f in `find . -name "*.rst"`; do

    lastline=`tail -n 1 $f`
    llstrip="$(echo -e "${lastline}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
    commdate=`git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd -- $f`

    if [[ "$llstrip" = "*Page last edited"* ]]; then
        sed -i "s/\*Page last edited [0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\*/\*Page last edited ${commdate}\*/" $f
    else
        echo "" >> $f
        echo "" >> $f
        echo '*Page last edited' "$commdate"'*' >> $f
    fi;

done


# Now you're done adding dates to the files.
# Quietly add the changed files to the last commit.
# But only do so for files that were included in the commits 
# since your branch deviated from the master,
# don't add untracked files without permission!

mybranch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
deviat=`git merge-base $mybranch master`

i=0
looping=true
while $looping; do
    i=$((i+1))
    cmtlist=`git log -n $i --format=%H`

    if [[ ${cmtlist} == *${deviat}* ]]; then
        looping=false
    fi
done

#cmtlist now contains all commit hashes since the branch deviated from the master.

added=false
for f in `git ls-files -m`; do
    comm=`git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- $f`
    if [[ ${cmtlist} == *${comm}* ]]; then

        if [[ ${modfiles} == *${f}* ]]; then
            # if changes in file not commited
            continue
        else
            git add $f
            added=true
        fi
    fi
done


if $added; then
    git commit --amend --no-edit --quiet
else
    echo 'Quickbuild script: nothing to add'
fi




#=============================================================================
# Make clean then rebuild
#=============================================================================

# rm `find . -name "*checkpoint.ipynb"` > /dev/null 2>&1
make clean
make html





exit 0
```

This will either add or update the date of the last commit in which any .rst file was changed to the end of the .rst file. The changes made will be quietly added to the commit provided the files were changed since the branch deviated from the master branch and have no modifications. The committing will fail during gitlab's automatic test, but that doesn't matter, because the correct dates will be in the file already, and the correct html pages can be built and synchronised to my server using a cronjob from my server's side. By running the script manually to quickly make clean and rebuild, it will however work.

The problem with solutions as suggested by Kevin Horn is that it only works locally because you set up your git config such that it automatically expands variables at every commit; Hoewer, I'd have to force all my collaborators to do exactly the same, which is why I went for this option.

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm a bit late, but I've just created a little Sphinx extension that gets the "last modified" time from Git:

https://github.com/mgeier/sphinx-last-updated-by-git/

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've managed to do this in the past is use something like Git Attributes.  Read this page:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

Especially take a look at the section titled "Keyword Expansion".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Date directive of rst.

At the top or bottom of your rst files, include the below text

```
.. |date| date::

Last Updated on |date|
```

In the final build, this date will be updated only when the source rst has been updated.

Reference: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/movpy-2.0.0-py2.4.4/manuals/docutils/ref/rst/directives.html#date

Comment: Note that this will insert the date at the time the document was **built**, which may or may not be when it was last **edited**.