# Sphinx footer update

Tags: python-sphinx

I have documentation in sphinx and I would like the date of the last modification to appear at the bottom of the page. I don't see how to do it or I don't see something similar

Comment: This is supported on most themes. You must have selected a theme that does not support it. What is the name of the Sphinx theme you are using?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53554636/407651

Comment: Sphinx version 3.1.1

Comment: That is not a Sphinx theme, but it is the version number. Look in your `conf.py` for the value of `html_theme`.

Comment: I still have not expressed myself well but I want to see in a sphinx document the modification date of said rst file.

Comment: The question that I linked to has four answers. Did you look at them?